# Android Xamarin: TabLayout Swipe on tab

Tags: android, xamarin, tabs, swipe, android-tablayout

i have a Problem using a TabLayout as simple buttons.

As you can see in the screenshot, my TabLayout Looks like this:

[image]

There are 2 Tabs "Starten" and "Abbrechen".
My problem is, that you can swipe on those Tabs. This often leads to the behavoir, that the tab is not recognized as "pressed", because the user has a very small movement of the finger while trying to press the tab, and this movement is recognized as a swipe.

If you look clearly, i captured the exact moment in the screenshot, when I clicked on "Abbrechen"-tab, but it was recognized as swipe. This is indicated by the very very light gray Color of the left side ob the tab.

Maybe you can help me how to disable this swipe or Change the sensitivity, that a Little movement is still recognized as click, not as swipe

EDIT: I did not implement the swipe.

I used a TabLayout in my Layout-File

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout  
     android:id="@+id/syncTabLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     app:tabMaxWidth="0dp" 
     app:tabGravity="fill"
     style="@style/SyncTabLayout"
     app:tabMode="fixed" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and added Tabs programmatically

```
_SyncTab = rootView.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.syncTabLayout);
_SyncTab.RemoveAllTabs();
                _SyncTab.AddTab(_SyncTab.NewTab().SetIcon(ContextCompat.GetDrawable((Activity as Context), Resource.Drawable.ic_syncStart)), false);
                _SyncTab.GetTabAt(0).SetText("Starten");
                _SyncTab.GetTabAt(0).SetTag("StartSync");
                _SyncTab.AddTab(_SyncTab.NewTab().SetIcon(ContextCompat.GetDrawable((Activity as Context), Resource.Drawable.ic_syncCancel)), false);
                _SyncTab.GetTabAt(1).SetText("Abbrechen");
                _SyncTab.GetTabAt(1).SetTag("CancelSync");
```

Comment: How did you implement the swipe function? And I think we'd likely need to see some code to help you pinpoint the problem

Comment: thanks for your response, I edited my question

Comment: Are you using [SetupWithViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setupWithViewPager(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)) method ?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a basic demo, to make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using?